# Evaluate limit with L^Hopital's rule if possible

Tags: limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I'm not sure how to use the L'Hopital's rule properly.

The question is $$ lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2 + \sin x }{x^2} $$

I tried replacing x by $\frac{1}{t}$ and limit to $ lim_{t\to 0} $ and use L'Hopital's rule so it becomes $ lim_{t\to 0} 1+ \frac{t^3 \cos t}{-2} $so the limit becomes 1 but it seems weird? can i just make the $\frac{t^3 \cos t}{-2} $ become 0? can someone double check this?

Comment: You have the right answer...  Everything you've done appears to be correct.  And yes, you can make the $t^3\text{(etc)}$ term $0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to use L'Hospital's rule, actually: We can do it directly by writing

$$\frac{x^2 + \sin x}{x^2} = 1 + \frac{\sin x}{x^2}$$

Now using the fact that $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ for all $x$, the squeeze theorem implies that the second term tends to zero, and the limit is $1$, as you've noticed.

---